# Folders without Namespaces C#, .Net, VS 2008

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, mvp

I'm working on an ASP.NET webapp using the MVP pattern, and as I'm organizing my files I'm wondering - are there conventions on folders within projects and how they relate to namespaces?

I have a bunch of controls and a bunch of pages, and I was going to throw them into Controls and Pages folders with subfolders, but I didn't know if it was bad form to do this if I wasn't also going to seperate them out into namespaces.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convention is to have classes that reside in a sub-namespace in a folder with the same name